# How to show/hide sidebar from panel

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

How can i show the `sidebar` ui component of my addon by clicking on the 'show-sidebar' `li` in the `panel` ui component? i tried the following:

#### panel.html

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li onclick="addon.port.emit ('login')">Login</li>
        <li onclick="addon.port.emit ('show-sidebar')">Show Sidebar</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

#### main.js

```
var sidebar = require("sdk/ui/sidebar").Sidebar ({...});
var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel (
{
    height: 59,
    width: 120,
    contentURL: Self.data.url("panel.html"),
    contentScriptWhen: "ready",
    onAttach: function()
    {       
        panel.port.on ("login", function (data)
        {
            Tabs.open ("login-page-url");
            panel.hide();
        });

        panel.port.on ("show-sidebar", function (data)
        {
            sidebar.show();
            panel.hide();
        });
    }
});
```

but it's giving me this error:

```
console.error: my-addon:
  Message: TypeError: sidebar.show is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

The inline javascript is not allowed in the embedded html. You should use the property `contentScriptFile` of [Panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#contentScriptFile).

I post you an example using your code.

**data/panel.html**

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li id="login">Login</li>
        <li id="sidebar">Show Sidebar</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

**data/script.js**

```
document.getElementById("login").onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById("login").innerHTML = "pouet";
}

document.getElementById("sidebar").onclick = function(){
    self.port.emit("show-sidebar");
}
```

**lib/main.js**

```
var sidebar = require("sdk/ui/sidebar").Sidebar ({
    id: 'my-sidebar',
    title: 'My sidebar',
    url: require("sdk/self").data.url("panel.html")
});
var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel (
{
    height: 150,
    width: 150,
    contentURL: require("sdk/self").data.url("panel.html"),
    contentScriptFile: require("sdk/self").data.url("script.js"),
    contentScriptWhen: "end"
});

panel.port.on("login", function (data) {
    console.log("event login");
    panel.hide();
});

panel.port.on("show-sidebar", function (data) {
    console.log("event show-sidebar");
    sidebar.show();
    panel.hide();
});

panel.show();
```

You can use another trigger event for when to loading js file see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#contentScriptWhen). I hope this example can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't change anything, i got the same error: `sidebar.show is not a function`. (btw you should use `self.port` instead of `addon.port` in a component content script file).

Comment: It is curious it works on my Firefox. Can you post anywhere your source code in a zip ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#Communicating_with_the_add-on